# implement array.prototype.reduce() on string

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I have some confusion regarding how reduce operation takes place on a string .First a new Str instance is created and sends desired string as a parameter.

Then using split method it  splits into an array of string.A reduceIt method takes the array and execute a reduce operation which returns the array element which has height length.

It works fine with a two element array.But if there is more than two elements it returns NAN.

Why it returns NAN for array having more than two elements??

```
function Str(text){
   this.text=text.split('\n');
}
Str.prototype.reduceIt = function() {
  return this.text.reduce(function(first,last,index,arr) {
          return Math.max(first.length,last.length);

  });
};

var t=new Str('i am a boy\n she loves cats\n a goat ate my flower garden ');
console.log(t.reduceIt());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first time the callback is called `first` is a string (the first element in the array), and your function makes sense when `first` and `last` are both strings, so it works when the callback is only called once (the array has at most 2 elements).

The second time it is called it is the result of the previous call, a `number`. When you call `first.length` on a number you get `undefined` and when you call `Math.max` on that you get `NaN`.

If you want to find the length of the longest string in your array, you could use:

```
Math.max.apply(Math, this.text.map(function (str) { return str.length; }));
```

Answer (score 2):

Some good answers already. :-)

The simple way to fix your problem is to supply an initial value of 0, then compare the returned value with the length of the new string, so:

```
Str.prototype.reduceIt = function() {
  return this.text.reduce(function(first,last,index,arr) {

          // Compare current value (first) with length of string
          return Math.max(first,last.length);

  }, 0); // supply 0 as the initial value
};
```

It might make things clearer to rename *first* to *maxSoFar* and *last* to *currentString*.

Answer (score 1):

> Why it returns NAN for array having more than two elements??

Because `number.length` is *undefined*, let's name your function `foo` and follow how it's invoked

1. `foo(0, "i am a boy")` gives `NaN`
2. `foo(NaN, " she loves cats")` gives `NaN`
3. `foo(NaN, " a goat ate my flower garden ")` gives `NaN`

Giving a final result of `NaN`.

This happens because `number.length` is *undefined* and `Math.max(undefined, x)` is `NaN`

It looks like you wanted to write a function which only takes the *length* of the second arg

```
function foo(a, b) {
    return Math.max(a, b.length);
}
```

In this case, you'll get

1. `foo(0, "i am a boy")` gives `10`
2. `foo(10, " she loves cats")` gives `15`
3. `foo(15, " a goat ate my flower garden ")` gives `29`

Giving a final result of `29`.

Comment: And the call is: `this.text.reduce(function(...) {...}, 0)`, i.e. an initial value is supplied of 0.